# Visual Studio 2008/2010 & SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, windows-7

Are there any limitations with respect to developing ASP.NET and WPF apps using VS 2008/2010 and SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 Home Premium?

I know you can run IIS 7.5 on Home Premium.  I Googled and Binged on Home Premium and VS/SQL Server and couldn't find much. It doesn't look like the features missing from Home Premium, domain joining, xp mode, etc... shouldn't prevent one from running and developing in VS/SQL Server.

**Update**

I did discover one limitation w/IIS 7.5 and it applies to all versions of Windows 7 I think.  You can't create your own self signed SSL certificate specifying a name other than the machine name. You're stuck with your machine name which isn't that big a deal, but it is a change from previous versions.

**Update II**

You can't do remote debugging on Home Premium.  msvsmon won't run at all.  I can't even get it to do remote debugging natively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual studio will run fine.  You will be "limited" to either SQL Server Express, or SQL Server Developer edition as the mssql installer checks the OS version and will refuse to install the higher end editions on desktop OSes.  Note that developer edition is the exact same as the higher end editions, except with a different license, you can only use it for development, not to run real databases.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on SQL Server. I have the dev edition, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, and you won't have any trouble with it.

In general, application compatibility is not affected by the edition (not version) of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider what the target infrastructure (Windows/IIS, .net, SQL Server etc versions) would be if you want to deploy it...

Comment: With regards to ASP.NET, target infrastructure is an ASP.NET host like DiscountAsp, so that would be Windows Server 2008/IIS 7/SQL Server 2008 and my web app corresponds to the host, so that should be OK, no?

For WPF, would there be a problem if an app were written on Home Premium and distributed on Professional versions, given that they don't utilize any Professional version features?

Comment: Not sure about WPF, sorry, but deploying "up" should be OK. I've seen errors recently with folk with different versions all over (eg SQL 2000 prod SQL 2005 dev. Or XP/IIS 5 dev, IIS 6 prod). Just thuoght I'd mention it