# will all windows 7 versions be suitable for a development machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7

So windows premium/standard/ultimate, are these versions all ok for a development computer?

ie. do any prevent installations of things like sql server, vs.net,etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any version except Starter, and everything will work fine.

Comment: You don't need to join a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Standard does not allow for joining a domain, so any Windows Authentication you need to do from a domain controller wouldn't work.  EDIT:  *removed for accuracy :)

Starter has some pretty tough limitations, wouldn't go there.

Comment: [Actually, you can install IIS on any version.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See here for a comparison between the versions, you should be fine with these 3 versions unless you need to join a domain

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/compare/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

More details in a question I asked similar to this here: [Visual Studio 2008/2010 & SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 Home Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815707/visual-studio-2008-2010-sql-server-2008-on-windows-7-home-premium)